# Need Calendar Instance only date (not time) and compare with date String in Kotlin as it lags

Tags: java, android, date, kotlin, calendar

I need only date from Calendar Instance not the time. Whenever i used calendar object it returns the date with time.

```
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
calendar.time. // Mon Nov 09 11:41:29 GMT 2020
```

I change this by using SimpleDateFormat

```
SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(date)

09/09/2020
```

I am creating calendar so i have huge amount of data in list. I am adding data at specific date. So I am comparing dates with string date. My string date Format is look like this :-

```
20/05/2020
```

So there is too much performance issue like lagging the view. So is there any thing which i can use to avoid all this thing.

```
val calendarModel = dataList?.find {
     SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(it.date) == item
}
```

Comment: Maybe execute `find` in a background thread to avoid overload on UI thread?

Comment: @BenShmuel Thanks for your reply. I am already using suspend function on this.

Comment: `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) is just a date without time of day. I don’t know if that means it carries a smaller overhead than `Calendar`. You may try. `Calendar` surely tries to be everything: date, time, time zone, week scheme and what not. In any case the `Calendar` class is poorly designed and long outdated, so should not be your first choice anyway.

Comment: @OleV.V. thanks for replying. Local Date requires android O notation my device supports  less than O also in android

Comment: See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time.

Comment: @OleV.V. thanks i'll check this. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Calendar#getTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime()) returns a `java.util.Date` object representing this Calendar's time value **which is a millisecond value** that is an offset from the Epoch, `January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT`.

Thus, `java.util.Date` does not represent a real date or time or date-time object. When you print this millisecond value, your JVM calculates the date and time in its time-zone and when you print its object, you get what `java.util.Date#toString` returns. From this explanation, you must have already understood that this millisecond value will be the same irrespective of the timezone as it is not a timezone based value; rather, it is fakely represented by `java.util.Date#toString` as a timezone based value. Just to demonstrate what I have just said, look at the output of the following program:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date();

        System.out.println("Asia/Calcutta:");
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
        System.out.println(date.getTime());
        System.out.println(date);

        System.out.println("\nEurope/London:");
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
        System.out.println(date.getTime());
        System.out.println(date);

        System.out.println("\nAfrica/Johannesburg:");
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Africa/Johannesburg"));
        System.out.println(date.getTime());
        System.out.println(date);

        System.out.println("\nAmerica/New_York:");
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
        System.out.println(date.getTime());
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Asia/Calcutta:
1604747702688
Sat Nov 07 16:45:02 IST 2020

Europe/London:
1604747702688
Sat Nov 07 11:15:02 GMT 2020

Africa/Johannesburg:
1604747702688
Sat Nov 07 13:15:02 SAST 2020

America/New_York:
1604747702688
Sat Nov 07 06:15:02 EST 2020
```

The [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) has real date-time classes. Given below is an [overview](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) of these classes:

[image]

As you can find in this table, there is a class, `LocalDate` which represents just date (consisting of a year, month, and day). Given below is a quick demo of the modern `java.time` API:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // A date with the given year, month and day-of-month
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2010, Month.NOVEMBER, 7);
        System.out.println(date);

        // Today (in the JVM's timezone)
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(); // Same as LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())
        System.out.println(today);

        // Today at UTC
        LocalDate todayAtUTC = LocalDate.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(todayAtUTC);

        // Today in India
        LocalDate todayInIndia = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Calcutta"));
        System.out.println(todayAtUTC);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2010-11-07
2020-11-07
2020-11-07
2020-11-07
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API at **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Recommendation:** The date-time API of `java.util` and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. I suggest you should stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).